# How do I change multiple pandas Dataframes at once using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two DataFrames that are nearly identical in structure, and I want to perform data transformation/cleaning on them simultaneously. To do this, I created a list that contains both of these DFs and loop through the list.

ex:

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
combined = [train, test]
for dataset in combined:
    dataset = dataset.drop(['Age'], axis =1)
    print(dataset.head())
```

The final print statement in the *for* loop works fine -- the 'Age' column is dropped.  However, if I immediately call *train.head()*, then the dropped column is still present in the DataFrame. It's almost as though two copies of "train" and "test" are being created --- the ones inside the "combined" list and the ones outside.  Is there something I need to do to make these changes persist?

This seems like it should be so simple, and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new dataset variable at each loop, and the operation is performed on those. So you are indeed, as you say, creating copies of train and test. What you want is to [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) that column `inplace`, rather than re-assigning:

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
combined = [train, test]
for dataset in combined:
    dataset.drop(['Age'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
    # print(dataset.head())
```

Note that another solution would just be to ignore those columns when you [load them](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', usecols=lambda x: x!='Age')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=lambda x: x!='Age')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!  Do you know why my transformation didn't work? I'm surprised both expressions wouldn't be equivalent.

As for omitting columns at import -- I used their values as part of calculating a different field, but didn't want to clutter the question with superfluous text. Thanks for providing the example though!

Comment: Because when you say `dataset = dataset.drop(...)`, it's creating a **new** dataframe, on which you're applying `drop`. The original dataframe is not modified in any way.

Comment: Oh, so I was thinking that "dataset" in that scenario is a placeholder for "train" and "test", and that expression within  would be `train = train.drop(...)` and `test = test.drop(...)'.  Does that mean that my above expression created a _third_ dataframe name "dataset"?

Comment: That's right, and it will have the values from the *last* dataframe in `combined` after the loop is done. That will be the only dataset in which `Age` was actually dropped.

Comment: Interesting... So if my function did not have an `inplace` argument available, would it be impossible to loop through dataframes in this fashion? An Example I'm thinking of might be:

`for dataset in [train,test]:
    dataset['Sex'] = dataset['Sex'].map({'male':0, 'female':1}).astype(int)`

Comment: Yes, that would work, because you are in fact re-assigning a value to the dataframe in that case. It's just that the `drop` function doesn't do anything inplace unless you tell it to.

Comment: could you help me here @sacuL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74008162/working-on-multiple-data-frames-with-data-for-nba-players-during-the-season-how | I would really appreciate your input.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @sacul's answer, there are more common ways to modify values in list  like this:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4] # any list
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = elem + 1 # can be any method here
lst
Out[24]: [2, 3, 4, 5]
```