# Working on multiple data frames with data for NBA players during the season, how can I modify all the dataframes at the same time?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, multiple-columns

I have a list of 16 dataframes that contain stats for each player in the NBA during the respective season. My end goal is to run unsupervised learning algorithms on the data frames. For example, I want to see if I can determine a player's position by their stats or if I can determine their total points during the season based on their stats.

**What I would like to do is modify *the list*(`df_list`), unless there's a better solution, of these dataframes instead modifying *each* dataframe to:**

1. Change the datatype of the `MP`(minutes played column from `str` to `int`.
2. Modify the dataframe where there are only players with 1000 or more `MP` and there are no duplicate players(`Rk`)

*(for instance in a season, a player(`Rk`) can play for three teams in a season and have 200`MP`, 300`MP`, and 400`MP` mins with each team. He'll have a column for each team **and** a column called `TOT` which will render his `MP` as 900(200+300+400) *for a total of four rows in the dataframe*. **I only need the `TOT` row***

3. Use simple algebra with various and individual columns columns, for example: being able to total the `MP` column and the `PTS` column and then diving the sum of the `PTS` column by the `MP` column.
   Or dividing the total of the `PTS` column by the `len` of the `PTS` column.

**What I've done so far is this:**

Import my libraries and create 16 dataframes using `pd.read_html(url)`.

The first dataframes created using two lines of code:

```
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1997_totals.html"

ninetysix = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

[image]

**HOWEVER**, the next four data frames had to be created using a few additional line of code(I received an error code that said *"html5lib not found, please install it"* so I downloaded both `html5lib` and `requests`). I say that to say...this distinction in creating the DF may have to considered in a solution.

**The code I used:**

```
import requests
import uuid

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1998_totals.html'
cookies = {'euConsentId': str(uuid.uuid4())}

html = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content
ninetyseven = pd.read_html(html)[0]
```

**These four data frames look like this:**

[image]

**I tried this but it didn't do anything:**

```
df_list = [
    eightyfour, eightyfive, eightysix, eightyseven, 
           eightyeight, eightynine, ninety, ninetyone, 
           ninetytwo, ninetyfour, ninetyfive,
    ninetysix, ninetyseven, ninetyeight, owe_one, owe_two
          ]
for df in df_list:
    df = df.loc[df['Tm'] == 'TOT']
    df = df.copy()
    df['MP'] = df['MP'].astype(int)
    df['Rk'] = df['Rk'].astype(int)
    df = list(df[df['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk'])
    df = df[df['Rk'].isin(df)]
owe_two
```

============================UPDATE===================================

This code will solves a portion of problem # 2

```
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1997_totals.html'
dd = pd.read_html(url)[0]
dd = dd[dd['Rk'].ne('Rk')]  
dd['MP'] = dd['MP'].astype(int)

players_1000_rk_list = list(dd[dd['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk'])
players_dd = dd[dd['Rk'].isin(players_1000_rk_list)]
```

But it doesn't remove the duplicates.

==================== UPDATE 10/11/22 ================================

Let's say I take rows with values "TOT" in the "Tm" and create a *new* DF with them, and these rows from the *original* data frame...

could I then compare the *new* DF with the *original* data frame and remove the names from the *original data* **IF** they match the names from the *new data* frame?

Comment: those new df's are not changed in place it is a different df than whats in your list... either set the index in the list to the new dataframe, or add it to a new list or something (if you printed those dataframes in the for loop you would see they are not the same as what you see in the list after)

Comment: That makes sense...but how would I do either of your suggestions? @JoranBeasley

Comment: is ```the_list[i] = new_df``` supposed to be under the for loop? if so...will each dataframe now have a new name? I don't understand the part where you wrote ```= new_df``` because it would be undefined @JoranBeasley

Comment: see my answer for clarity :P

Comment: that makes **a lot** more sense now that it's written out. Thanks!! I will research ```enumerate``` as well because that is new to me. I'm now getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" for the second to last line in the for loop...but I should be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the `df` you are working on in the loop is not the same df that is in the `df_list`. you could solve this by saving the new df back to the list, overwriting the old df

```
for i,df in enumerate(df_list):
    df = df.loc[df['Tm'] == 'TOT']
    df = df.copy()
    df['MP'] = df['MP'].astype(int)
    df['Rk'] = df['Rk'].astype(int)
    df = list(df[df['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk'])
    df = df[df['Rk'].isin(df)]
    df_list[i] = df
```

the2 lines are probably wrong as well

```
    df = list(df[df['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk'])
    df = df[df['Rk'].isin(df)]
```

perhaps you want this

```
for i,df in enumerate(df_list):
    df = df.loc[df['Tm'] == 'TOT']
    df = df.copy()
    df['MP'] = df['MP'].astype(int)
    df['Rk'] = df['Rk'].astype(int)
    #df = list(df[df['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk'])
    #df = df[df['Rk'].isin(df)]
    # just the rows where MP > 1000
    df_list[i] = df[df['MP'] >= 1000]
```

Comment: thank you. I'm getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" in regard to the second to last line of the four loop but I should be able to figure that out.

Comment: thats your line ... i didnt change that ... but you did convert it to a list right before that so it makes sense, that you cannot index it with `"Rk"`...presumably you must have had that problem before as well and didnt mention it... not sure what that line is supposed to be doing ... but its probably going to result in an empty df if you get past the syntax errors

Comment: @Fitzgerald see edits to my answer ... which might be what you want

Comment: That's 100% my line, I wasn't trying to insinuate that was your fault at all. I did have that error before but I forgot to mention it. If I put the line ```df= df[df['Rk'].isin(df)]``` before the ```df = list(df[df['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk'])``` line...I don't get the error but I don't get the result I want.

Comment: I updated my question with a solution to one portion of problem #2